# CSS3 Animations, Unable to create links in animated div

Tags: html, css

Ok so im creating a slideshow effect with CSS3 animations and Im attempting to create links in the div containing the text that slides out to the right as each transition occurs I want different links for each slide. Please help as I need this website to go live as soon as possible. cheers in advance!

CSS/HTML

```css
.slides {
    height:420px;
    margin:50px auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
 max-width: 1150px;
}
.slides ul {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
}


@-webkit-keyframes anim_slides {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    6% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    24% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    30% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes anim_slides {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    6% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    24% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    30% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}

.slides ul li  {
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;

  
    -webkit-animation-name: anim_slides;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 16.0s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    -moz-animation-name: anim_slides;
    -moz-animation-duration: 16.0s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


.slides ul  li:nth-child(2), .slides ul  li:nth-child(2) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4.0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 4.0s;
}



.slides ul  li:nth-child(3), .slides ul  li:nth-child(3) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 8.0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 8.0s;
 
}
.slides ul  li:nth-child(4), .slides ul  li:nth-child(4) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12.0s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12.0s;
 
}
.slides ul li img{
    display:block;
}


@-webkit-keyframes anim_titles {
    0% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    5% {
        left:60%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    20% {
        left:60%;
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:1;
    }
    100% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes anim_titles {
    0% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    5% {
        left:60%;
        opacity:1;
    }
    20% {
        left:60%;
        opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        left:100%;
        opacity:0;
    }
}




.slides ul li div {
    background-color:#000000;
    border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px #FFFFFF inset;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-size:26px;
    left:60%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    width:200px;


    -webkit-animation-name: anim_titles;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 16.0s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

    -moz-animation-name: anim_titles;
    -moz-animation-duration: 16.0s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-direction: normal;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0;
    -moz-animation-play-state: running;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
    <div class="slides">
    
    
     <ul> <!-- slides -->
      <li><img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/curiousBabyBoy.png" alt="image01" />
       <div class="hvr-back-pulse">Book a Demo...</div>
      </li>
      <li><img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/mom_baby.png" alt="image02" />
       <div class="hvr-back-pulse">Find Out More...</div>
      </li>
      <li><img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/mom_phone.png" alt="image03" />
       <div class="hvr-back-pulse">Promo text #3</div>
      </li>
      <li><img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/mom_phone.png" alt="image04" />
       <div class="hvr-back-pulse">Promo text #4</div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You may want to look @ http://benschwarz.github.io/gallery-css/

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
<li></li>
```

To make links you have to use anchor tags:

```
<a href="web address of your link (url)"></a>
```

Comment: i know that lol the problem is when i add an achor tag the link only works for the last text that comes up (4th element)

Comment: @SamOgden-Palmer You would avoid this kind of issues if the code that you post **had** the anchors

Answer (score 0):

I have just added the link for each div.

[Here is a working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bpqq8fv7/)

```
<div class="slides">
                <ul> <!-- slides -->
                    <li><img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/curiousBabyBoy.png" alt="image01" />
                        <div class="hvr-back-pulse"><a href="http://www.google.com">Book a Demo...</a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/mom_baby.png" alt="image02" />
        <div class="hvr-back-pulse"><a href="http://www.google.com">Find Out More...</a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/mom_phone.png" alt="image03" />
        <div class="hvr-back-pulse"><a href="http://www.google.com">Promo text #3</a></div>
                    </li>
                    <li><img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/mom_phone.png" alt="image04" />
        <div class="hvr-back-pulse"><a href="http://www.google.com">Promo text #4</a></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try wrapping the text inside the divs with a tags and links them.

```html
<div class="slides">


  <ul>
    <!-- slides -->
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/curiousBabyBoy.png" alt="image01" />
      <div class="hvr-back-pulse"><a href="link1">Book a Demo...</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/mom_baby.png" alt="image02" />
      <div class="hvr-back-pulse"><a href="link2">Find Out More...</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/mom_phone.png" alt="image03" />
      <div class="hvr-back-pulse"><a href="link3">Promo text #3</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/mom_phone.png" alt="image04" />
      <div class="hvr-back-pulse"><a href="link4">Promo text #4</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.slides {

  height: 420px;

  margin: 50px auto;

  overflow: hidden;

  position: relative;

  width: 100%;

  max-width: 1150px;

}

.slides ul {

  list-style: none;

  position: relative;

}

@-webkit-keyframes anim_slides {

  0% {

    opacity: 0;

  }

  6% {

    opacity: 1;

  }

  24% {

    opacity: 1;

  }

  30% {

    opacity: 0;

  }

  100% {

    opacity: 0;

  }

}

@-moz-keyframes anim_slides {

  0% {

    opacity: 0;

  }

  6% {

    opacity: 1;

  }

  24% {

    opacity: 1;

  }

  30% {

    opacity: 0;

  }

  100% {

    opacity: 0;

  }

}

.slides ul li {

  opacity: 0;

  position: absolute;

  top: 0;

  -webkit-animation-name: anim_slides;

  -webkit-animation-duration: 16.0s;

  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;

  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;

  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  -moz-animation-name: anim_slides;

  -moz-animation-duration: 16.0s;

  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

  -moz-animation-direction: normal;

  -moz-animation-delay: 0;

  -moz-animation-play-state: running;

  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

.slides ul li:nth-child(2),

.slides ul li:nth-child(2) div {

  -webkit-animation-delay: 4.0s;

  -moz-animation-delay: 4.0s;

}

.slides ul li:nth-child(3),

.slides ul li:nth-child(3) div {

  -webkit-animation-delay: 8.0s;

  -moz-animation-delay: 8.0s;

}

.slides ul li:nth-child(4),

.slides ul li:nth-child(4) div {

  -webkit-animation-delay: 12.0s;

  -moz-animation-delay: 12.0s;

}

.slides ul li img {

  display: block;

}

@-webkit-keyframes anim_titles {

  0% {

    left: 100%;

    opacity: 0;

  }

  5% {

    left: 60%;

    opacity: 0;

  }

  20% {

    left: 60%;

    opacity: 1;

  }

  25% {

    left: 100%;

    opacity: 1;

  }

  100% {

    left: 100%;

    opacity: 0;

  }

}

@-moz-keyframes anim_titles {

  0% {

    left: 100%;

    opacity: 0;

  }

  5% {

    left: 60%;

    opacity: 1;

  }

  20% {

    left: 60%;

    opacity: 1;

  }

  25% {

    left: 100%;

    opacity: 0;

  }

  100% {

    left: 100%;

    opacity: 0;

  }

}

.slides ul li div {

  background-color: #000000;

  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;

  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #FFFFFF inset;

  color: #FFFFFF;

  font-size: 26px;

  left: 60%;

  margin: 0 auto;

  padding: 20px;

  position: absolute;

  top: 50%;

  width: 200px;

  -webkit-animation-name: anim_titles;

  -webkit-animation-duration: 16.0s;

  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;

  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;

  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;

  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

  -moz-animation-name: anim_titles;

  -moz-animation-duration: 16.0s;

  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;

  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;

  -moz-animation-direction: normal;

  -moz-animation-delay: 0;

  -moz-animation-play-state: running;

  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="slides">


    <ul>
      <!-- slides -->
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/curiousBabyBoy.png" alt="image01" />
        <div class="hvr-back-pulse"><a href="1" class="demo">Book a Demo...</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/mom_baby.png" alt="image02" />
        <div class="hvr-back-pulse"><a href="2" class="demo">Find Out More...</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/mom_phone.png" alt="image03" />
        <div class="hvr-back-pulse"><a href="3" class="demo">Promo text #3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/2/1/5/2/21528596/custom_themes/981467400795039554/files/mom_phone.png" alt="image04" />
        <div class="hvr-back-pulse"><a href="4" class="demo">Promo text #4</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you notice the problem is that when you click on any of the links they all point to the link text on the 4th slide.